# Omitting a referenced column from the group-by clause

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT GEOGRAPHY , PROJECT ,
  CASE
    WHEN project_name = 'test1'
    THEN 'test1'
    WHEN project_name = 'test2'
    THEN 'test2'
    WHEN project_name    = 'test3'
    AND test_NAME = 'samp1'
    THEN 'gen1'
    WHEN project_name     = 'test3'
    AND  TEST_name <> 'samp1'
    THEN 'gen2'
    ELSE project_name
  END PROJECT_NAME from table 1
group by 
geography ,project_name,test_name.
```

I get the below data -

```
Geography  Project_name  Test_name  Actual count  Plan count
Russia     test1         samp4                 3           3
Russia     test1         samp5                66          19
Russia     test1         samp2               133          79
Russia     gen1          samp1               170          16
Vietnam    test1         samp2                35          17
Vietnam    gen1          samp1                91           4
```

I would like to group by only geography and project_name:

```
Geography  Project name actual count
Russia     test1                 202
Russia     Gen1                  170
Vietnam    Test1                  35
Vietnam    Gen1                   91
```

I got answer for this question...

```
 SELECT GEOGRAPHY ,  
      CASE
        WHEN project_name = 'test1'
        THEN 'test1'
        WHEN project_name = 'test2'
        THEN 'test2'
        WHEN project_name    = 'test3'
        AND test_NAME = 'samp1'
        THEN 'gen1'
        WHEN project_name     = 'test3'
        AND  TEST_name <> 'samp1'
        THEN 'gen2'
        ELSE project_name
      END PROJECT_NAME from table 1
    group by 
    geography ,CASE
        WHEN project_name = 'test1'
        THEN 'test1'
        WHEN project_name = 'test2'
        THEN 'test2'
        WHEN project_name    = 'test3'
        AND test_NAME = 'samp1'
        THEN 'gen1'
        WHEN project_name     = 'test3'
        AND  TEST_name <> 'samp1'
        THEN 'gen2'
        ELSE project_name
      END .
```

This worked....and thanks everyone who tried to assist me.

Comment: What if there is more than one test name for a geography/project name combination? (Not relevant really, but the first two when clauses seem redundant, since they are covered by the else?)

Comment: Please don't use comments to post code or make corrections. i've edited the question for you this time (so you can delete your comment if I've done it right). But that still doesn't address what you want to happen if there are two test names.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any difference between your current output and what you want to get?

Comment: I want below Actual count and Plan count to be added. In the below if I group by geography and project name it adds..but cannot do that since I have to group by geography name, project name and test_name                      Geography  Project_name  Test_name  Actual count  Plan count
Russia     test1         samp4                 3           3
Russia     test1         samp5                66          19
Russia     test1         samp2               133          79

Comment: That's still the same first three rows of output. Please the question to show what output you actually *want* to see. Which columns, which values they should have, and what the aggregate counts should be. I suspect you want one row for Russia,test1,202,101; and a second row for Russia,gen1,170,16; etc. But it still isn't clear. Showing your actual current query might help too. (Again, in the question, not as a comment).

Comment: I have edited how my output should look like...Thanks

Comment: Ok, then did you try ksa's approach?

Comment: Could you help me with the query/sub query/aggregation please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select geography, project_name
  from ( select geography
              , project
              , case when project_name = 'test1' then 'test1'
                     when project_name = 'test2' then 'test2'
                     when project_name = 'test3'
                       and test_name = 'samp1' then 'gen1'
                     when project_name = 'test3'
                       and test_name <> 'samp1' then 'gen2'
                     else project_name
                     end project_name
           from table1 )
 group by geography, project_name
```

Comment: Script will compile: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a3c0c/1 Group by apply on sub-query.

Comment: Sorry, I completely misread it - you're right.It still doesn't answer the question though; the OP seems to want to include the column's they have; but their SQL is inconsistent between what's being selected and what's being grouped. They need to make a decision still, rather than just removing the column (there's no need for a sub-select if they want to do that)/

Comment: As far as I understand the OP tries to calculate new column from project_name and test_name and then to group records. It can be done with sub-query or with aggregate function for test_name column.

Comment: I think this answer may very well be the correct answer, although without sample data and desired results it is a bit hard to tell.

Comment: If this is what the OP wants then it can be achieved with distinct and no subquery. It doesn't need grouping as there is (currently) no aggregation. It isn't clear what the data is or output shpuld be though.

Comment: I think I should have given more information. There is Aggregation but did not mention it in the SQL. I will edit and put some data how my current SQL works in the main page so that everyone understands the requirement. Sorry, I'm new to Forums